# Stick/fix above-the-fold element to top

Tags: javascript, css

Stumbled upon this example on the web

https://redq.io/react-next-landing

So how is this effect called that the main slider seems to be unmovable and the rest of the body covers it while scrolling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually `position: fixed`. Fixed removes the element from the normal document flow which `sticky` does not. For this to proberly work the scrolling part has to be "above" the top part. Which is done with `z-index: int` as you can see in the following screenshot:

[image: z-index example]

You can read more about in the link shared by Roko.

Comment: Thanks!/ Dzięki! :)

Comment: nie ma za co :)

Comment: @SzymonDzumak By using `position: fixed; `  you'll have to separately handle the top position of any other element which comes "below" your *sticky* one, like i.e: by using `#nextAfterSlideshow {top: 100vh;}` - but, with position **sticky** that is not necessary.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan you can set the top part `position: fixed` and the container for the rest too. In the example he showed above you would need to change a lot more to make it work with `position: sticky` but obviously both options work.

Answer (score 1):

It's called **sticky**
Achieved using CSS `position: sticky;` and `top: /*i.e:*/ 0px;` you can find more info here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

If the element was just to move at a different pace (slower then the rest of the document scroll) than it would be called: **parallax**.

Sticky slideshow example:

```css
/* Quick Reset */ * {margin:0; box-sizing: border-box;}

header,
main,
footer {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

header {min-height: 100vh; background: gold; position: sticky; top: 0; }
main   {min-height: 100vh; background: white;}
footer {min-height: 50vh;  background: grey;}
```

```html
<header><h1>ABOVE THE FOLD SLIDESHOW</h1></header>
<main><div>MAIN CONTENT</div></main>
<footer><div>Footer links etc</div></footer>
```